# Select Show Content Relating to Option

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to show content only related to the selected option in a dropdown.

I've put together a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/7u7qebr5/4/).

Once an option is selected, I would like to show the bound elements for that specific model. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Do I need to use `$root`, or am I missing a piece of the `select` API?

### HTML

```
<div id="defAccount">
<p>
    Account Option :
    <select data-bind="options: accounts,
                   optionsText: 'accountNumber',
                    value: 'Id', 
                    optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div data-bind="visible: accounts().length > 0">
            <label data-bind="text: accounts.Id"></label>
            <label data-bind="text: accounts.accountNumber"></label>
            <label data-bind="text: accounts.participantName"></label>
              <div data-bind="visible: accounts().length < 1">
              <label>There are currently no records to show - sucka.</label>
            </div>
        </div>        

    </div>
</p>
</div>
```

### Knockout

```
// Model
function deferredAccount(data) {
          //  var self = this;

            this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
            this.accountNumber = ko.observable(data.AccountNumber);
            this.participantName = ko.observable(data.ParticipantName);
        }

//ViewModel
function accountViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.accounts = ko.observableArray([]); 

        $.ajax("/echo/json/", {
        data: {
            json: ko.toJSON(account)
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
                //2 objects here
            var mAccounts = _.map(data, function(item) {
                return new deferredAccount(item);
            });

            console.log(mAccounts);

            self.accounts(mAccounts);
        }
    });  

}

// Copy
var account = [
    {"Id":1,
     "AccountNumber":100011,
     "ParticipantName":"MICKEY MOUSE"
    },
    {"Id":3,
     "AccountNumber":200011,
     "ParticipantName":"MICKEY MOUSE"
    }
];


ko.applyBindings(new accountViewModel(), document.getElementById("defAccount"));
```

Comment: accounts is an observableArray, but you are trying to display members Id, accountNumber, and participantName from it, as if it were a single object.

Comment: simple try this nothing much to modify http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/7u7qebr5/8/. cheers

Comment: @supercool I wish you posted an answer! I went with your method, however dperry's solution also works. I do prefer your method though. I appreciate it! If you post an answer I'll upvote

Comment: glad it helps . @dperry solution is same except `with` part so cool .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your selection on the viewmodel and bind your form to the actual selection, not the backing array:

http://jsfiddle.net/7u7qebr5/9/

html:

```
<select data-bind="options: accounts,
                       optionsText: 'accountNumber',
                        value: selectedAccount, 
                        optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
... 

<label data-bind="text: selectedAccount().Id"></label>
<label data-bind="text: selectedAccount().accountNumber"></label>
<label data-bind="text: selectedAccount().participantName"></label>
```

observable:

```
self.selectedAccount = ko.observable();
```

Comment: That's it! I appreciate it. I had gone down this route before but I think I tried to access the observable incorrectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are some missing parts on your select

if you wants to bind all datas which selcted your select should be like this

```
<select data-bind="options: accounts,
       optionsText: 'accountNumber', value: selectedOption, 
       optionValue  :$data,
       optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
```

This code bind selected options all data to selectedOption or you can bind only an attribute of selected option with change **optionValue  :'Id'**,
and dont forget define selectedOption